# How can I undo an edit in Gmail's compose field?

Tags: gmail, 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-s-9, text-input

How can I undo an edit in Gmail's compose field?

For example, I write a draft email, select the entire text and remove it, how can I undo my remove action to get the text back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JinaneK was on the correct path suggesting to used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. You will need to install a keyboard that has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key such as [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) if your keyboard app does not have it.

After you delete a text, open Hacker's Keyboard (if it was not already opened), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (you will see an indication on the key that it is activated, on my phone, the indication was a blue line), then press on <kbd>Z</kbd>. You can even use it to redo by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>

**Disclaimer:** I am just a user of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if the session is not closed just an undo or ctrl+z can do it.

Comment: Thanks, how do you do Ctrl+z or undo on Android?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Hacker's keyboard app can help you with that.